# Dynamically update a textView from a Custom Object in Android

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to update a TextView in main activity from inside a custom object.

The custom object is a number picker written from scratch. It has an EditText and 2 button (+/-). 
My purpose is that when a user press the + or - button the TextView will be updated with that value.

Now i can think 2 possible solutions:

1. The custom object update the TextView when the + or - button is pressed (inside the onClickListener).
2. I define another class that extend the custom picker, with the logic for update the textview.

But my problem is that i want to keep the textView logic outside the custom picker (so if is possible to have the update function inside the activity). 
There is a solution to that problem?

The custompicker xml code is that:

```
<org.croncalc.MyPicker android:id="@+id/hourpicker"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                croncalc:maxnumber="24"
                croncalc:minnumber="1"
                croncalc:step="5"
                croncalc:cycle="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

[Here a screenshot](http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/3518/examplej.jpg)

I want that everytime one of the picker change its value the textview on the right corner will be updated.

If useful here the onClick() code for the +/- buttons:

```
    OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.decbtn:
            step(-1);
            break;
        case R.id.incbtn:
        default:
            step(1);
            break;
        }
    }                   
};

private void step(int step) {
    current += step;
    if (step > 0) {
        decButton.setEnabled(true);         
        if ( current > maxNumber) {
            if(cycle){
                current-=maxNumber;
            } else {
                current=maxNumber;
                incButton.setEnabled(false);
                incButton.setPressed(false);
            }           
        }
    } else {
        incButton.setEnabled(true);
        if ( current < minNumber) {
            if(cycle){
                current+= maxNumber;
            } else {
                current=minNumber;
                decButton.setEnabled(false);
                decButton.setPressed(false);
            }                       
        }
    }
    pickerText.setText(Integer.toString(current));      
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Ivan

Comment: If there is an EditText supposedly showing the ##, how does the TextView come into play here?  Maybe a screenshot or clarifacation?

Comment: you should provide some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i answer myself (i found a solution).

I define a CustomListener for my objcet. 
I declared an interface called: 
    package org.croncalc;
    public interface OnMyPickerChangeListener {
        public abstract void onMyPickerChanged(String srcTxt);
    }

and then i added in MyPickerClass (this is the name of the object) a new class Variable:

```
OnMyPickerChangeListener onMyPickerChangeListener;
```

That variable will be initialized at null.
After i defined in MyPicker two new methods:

1. The first is the setOnMyPickerChangeListener with that method i can add a OnMyPickerChangeListener:

   public void setOnMyPickerChangeListener(OnMyPickerChangeListener listener) {
       onMyPickerChangeListener = listener;
   }
2. The second method is onMyPickerChanged, that method will be called everytime we want to trigger the Change Event:

   private void onMyPickerChanged(){
       if(onMyPickerChangeListener!=null){
       onMyPickerChangeListener.onMyPickerChanged(pickerText.getText().toString());
       }
   }

Now in the main activity i declared a new OnMyPickerChangeListener and implemented the interface method onMyPickerchanged:

```
OnMyPickerChangeListener pickerListener = new OnMyPickerChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMyPickerChanged(String srcTxt) {          
        localTv.setText("Value: " + srcTxt);
    }
};
```

And i added that Listener to the Picker:

```
minutesPicker.setOnMyPickerChangeListener(pickerListener);
```

And now it works :)

Comment: i gave same thing as you answered

Answer (score 1):

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
     new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view,int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            //Update Here textView when you click on dialog     
                 };
 @Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Hope it Help you

Comment: I'm not sure, But my picker isn't a time picker. It is something different (the TimePicker didn't fit my purposes), then this code cannot apply to my problem..

Comment: ok i gave you code for idea,now you can used it as your requirement